# ssh not working and server inaccessible (server down)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have VM-Instances, working well with ubuntu 16.04, LAMPP and Wordpress since Dec 2017.

But since yesterday 25/04/18, when I was building wordpress in wp-admin, suddenly Wordpress gave error message "Error establishing a database connection". Immediately I checked GCP-console and access ssh. I suspect there was a problem with mysql (before this ever happened), so I rebooted the server and the server returned to normal, but only a few minutes. Then a database connection error occurs again. This time when I access SSH via console, it always comes out error message

"Connection Failed - An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration".

If I open the website was always out message "This site can not be reached". I've tried checking firewall configurations etc, but did not find any weirdness (because I did not make any changes).

so from yesterday to today, I can not access server in browser or via SSH. Server down / offline.

How to solve a suddenly problematic server like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to ssh with -vvv flags and post the output (remove usernames, IPs and so on before posting). Do you have any other means for accessing this VM? My guess is that your root (/) filesystem is full.

Comment: sorry, I can't accessing this VM. Do you have any suggestions for doing this?

Comment: debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XXX [XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/XX/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/XX/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Comment: Did you check the Disk size? I have had problems with SSH in the past where it cannot assign the tmp session file because of lack of space

Comment: Kindly contact the Google Cloud to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> so from yesterday to today, I can not access server in browser or via
>   SSH. Server down / offline.
>
> How to solve a suddenly problematic server like this?

Apart from having `regular ssh`, you should have `console access` to google cloud platform. (Console access is a sort of emergency/maintenance backdoor ) .If you don't have access to google cloud platform, ask for the person who created the vm for you.

if the vm is down start it,

```
 1. Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console. Open the console left side
 2. menu and select Compute Engine. On the left, select VM Instances.
 3. Select the checkboxes next to the instances that you want to start,
    and then click the Start button.
```

more.
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/restart-services

console access etc
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Support Options
https://cloud.google.com/support/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the serial console, this would need to be enabled.

> Edit the VM:
>
> Remote access
>   Enable connecting to serial ports

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console?hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Create a machine image for existing VM, create new VM instance using existing  VM. You will be able to SSH to new VM .No data will be lost.

You need to restart all the services.